# message after an action button "rich: notifyMessages "

Tags: validation, jsf, richfaces

I use "rich: notifyMessages" to display errors after validation issues,
but what I need now is to show the same kind of message after an action button, for example, using the "onComplete" tag?
the messages that i need to display is like this one : 
"congratulation the operation completed successfully" ...
tnx ..

Answer (score 0):

You could use the oncomplete to trigger a jsFunction that sets a faces message and then renders that message. I use that as confirmation that a newly composed e-mail has indeed been sent after the send button is pressed.

```
public static void addInfoMessage(String message) {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("info", new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, message, message));
}
```